# XEN configuration on dedicated server at 1&1

Tags: virtualization, xen, debian-squeeze

I am just trying to install first time VPS on my dedicated server from 1&1 (12HT CPU, 30 GB RAM). The dom0 is using DHCP to get it's network configuration with ip 87.106.73.113 on eth0. I have also bought extra ip 87.106.230.211 which firstly I was using as virtual interface of eth0.

Could someone tell me how should I configure XEN and dom0 to use 87.106.230.211 as ip of my virtual server? Should I leave commented gateway and broadcast in xen-tools.conf or find gateway to which is connecting dom0?

Should I also add to xend-config.sxp those lines or something else? :

```
(network-script 'network-bridge antispoof=yes')
(vif-script vif-bridge)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the network-script at its default.

Bridging is imho the most convenient way to network in xen, so leave it to default, too (which is bridging).

Now you should configure a bridge-device on your Dom0 and attach your phsical eth0 to it (with standard operating system means).

Use eth0 without IP, but make it "up" - configure the IP on the bridge-device.

For the DomU you have to attach its virtual network device to that bridge. Configuring the IP is then done within the DomU - in your case, use a fixed IP.